# How do I assign an element in a series of 3D arrays of into a single vector?

Tags: matlab

So I want all 6 elements of the third column to go into a vector of 6 elements. How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use the comparison operator to compare against an interval the way you do. I suggest you try to run this bit of code:

```
x = 1:10;
4 < x < 7
```

On my system I get the answer

```
ans =

 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

which, I suspect, is not what you want. The solution is to divide your condition like this

```
(4 < x) & (x < 7)
```

giving

```
ans =

 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

as expected.

Now, back to your actual question. If you know how many elements the resulting vector should have, then you can use `reshape`:

```
mask = (50 < seals(:, 3, 1)) & (seals(:, 3, 1) < 100)
x = nanmean(seals(mask, :, :));
v = reshape(x(:, 3, :), 6, 1);
```

However, in this case you're using a search criteria to find which values to select and therefore probably don't know beforehand how long the final vector will be. Another option is then to first retrieve the values you want and then reshape them into a vector using the colon operator `(:)` like this:

```
mask = (50 < seals(:, 3, 1)) & (seals(:, 3, 1) < 100)
x = nanmean(seals(mask, :, :));
y = x(:, 3, :);
v = y(:);
```

In both cases I've also introduced a separate selection mask to slightly increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (:) operator to collapse an nD matrix to a single vector. For your example, do something like this:

```
mat = (50 < seals(:, 3, 1)) & (seals(:, 3, 1) < 100)
vec = mat(:);
```